# Angle between 2 lines given the lengths

Tags: c++, math

I need help finding angle between 2 lines given the lengths, the solution I've found works for some angles. I would prefer a solution that results in a degree from 0 to 360, but its not that important.

```
 Angle i need lies between s1 and s2.

   s1  (2m)
  _________                        /|
           |  works        s1(2m) / |  
           |                     /  |s2(2m)
    s3     | s2(2m)             /   |
           |                     s3

//s3 is calculated from the start point of s1 and end of s2.

//this works for some angles but not all the time.
double GetAngle(double s1,double s2,double s3)
{
    double r=acos((pow(s1,2)+pow(s2,2)-pow(s3,2))/2*s1*s2);
    r=((180.0*a)/M_PI);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: How are you intending to distinguish between say, 10 degrees and 350 degrees?

Comment: You cannot do that, unless you impose other criteria. You will always come up with two angles, x and 360-x.

Comment: Your equation is incorrect and lacks parentheses in the denominator, it should be `r=acos((pow(s1,2)+pow(s2,2)-pow(s3,2))/(2*s1*s2));

Comment: I added the extra parentheses but the degree result is still wrong

Comment: You need to state the problem more clearly. What does it mean to "finding angle of 2 lines given the lengths"??? How many lengths are you given? Your picture does not seem to explain much.

Comment: Given only two side lengths, there can't be a unique answer. Case in point: consider two clock hands.

Comment: The lengths of the lines are irrelevant to the angle between them...

Comment: Are you trying to say that `s1, s2, s3` are the sides of a triangle, and you want the angle opposite `s3` ?

Comment: If so, your code (after fixing Cyber's point, and changing `a` to `r`) does look like a correct implementation of the cosine rule. It is not very helpful to say "the result is still wrong" . Instead please post a set of inputs along with the output that you think is wrong.

Comment: [See it working](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5f95d3ed781392f)

Comment: @MattMcNabb is also correct. We cannot help without you telling us what you are given, and the expected output for each input. Examples that work as expected and examples that don't quite work as intended would help greatly.

Comment: I think the OP mean what @MattMcNabb said.

Comment: r=((180.0*a)/M_PI); --> what is "a"?

Comment: @MattMcNabb function does not work with triangle side lengths `1, 1, 5`.  :)  maybe this is what the OP meant when he said it doesn't always work.  Teachable moment about error handling.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you require is a function the takes the lengths of 3 sides of a triangle and returns one of the angles. This requires application of the cosine rule, as mentioned in comments.

```
double GetAngle(double s1, double s2, double s3) {
    double r = acos((pow(s1, 2) + pow(s2, 2) - pow(s3, 2)) / (2 * s1 * s2));
    return (180.0 * r / PI);
}
```

At this point you have the internal angle of a triangle. If you actually need a bearing between points or lines you will have to apply a second condition to determine whether to use (for example) the angle A or (360 - A). This cannot be determined from the lengths alone, or from the information you have provided.